# Selenium webdriver username and password input from HTML attributes

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I have a python script which uses selenium webdriver to login and navigate a website. The login has been working successfully, but the company has updated their website and I cannot locate any "ID"/"Name"/attribute to use to enter the username and password.

The code **which did work** (Before the new website version) is:

```
try:
    elem_username = WebDriverWait(b, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'username')))
except TimeoutException:
    elem_username = None

# Wait for password to appear
try:
    elem_password = WebDriverWait(b, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'password')))
except TimeoutException:
    elem_password = None
```

When inspecting the newly deployed website, below is the html from the inspection window for username:

[HTML code from inspection window for username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70NO6.png)

Using other tags/functions what can I use to enter the username?
Here is the username HTML code from my inspection window when viewing the updated website:

```
<div>Version 1.4.4087</div></div><div class="login-form"><sip-input class="login-input login-style has-errors" sip-input-group="login" sip-model="$ctrl.username" sip-minlength="3" sip-maxlength="12" sip-placeholder-translation="USERNAME" sip-required="" sip-autofocus=""><input sip-scope-field="sipInputCtrl.inputElement" ng-attr-tabindex="{{sipInputCtrl._sipTabindex}}" class="sip-input-element ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-not-empty" ng-keydown="sipInputCtrl.onKeyDown($event)" ng-keyup="sipInputCtrl.onKeyUp($event)" type="text" step="1" maxlength="12" ng-model="sipInputCtrl.sipModel" autofocus="autofocus" tabindex="0"><!----><!----><!----><div class="sip-input-placeholder-big" translate="USERNAME" ng-if="::sipInputCtrl.isTranslation">User name</div><!----><!----><div class="sip-input-placeholder-small" translate="USERNAME" ng-if="::sipInputCtrl.isTranslation">User name</div><!----><ng-transclude><sip-input-error sip-error-minlength="" class="error-hidden"><ng-transclude><span translate="ENTERUSERNAME">Please enter your user name</span></ng-transclude></sip-input-error></ng-transclude><div class="sip-input-focus"></div>
```

Comment: Post the html as text, not image. what are the elements you are trying to find?

Comment: @guy I have updated the question with the HTML. Essentially I am trying to replace the username and password tags in the python script, as these have been removed from the website, and want to replace them with something else which will work for input of username and password in my script. The html code image shows the available attributes to use (for the username), but i am not sure how to make it work with them.